# executing .net application on mac using mono gives 99% on Assembly.LoadFrom

Tags: c#, macos, mono

Im trying to execute a .Net application (wallparse firewall audit tool) on mac using mono. The vendor gives no support for mac, but I would really love to use it on my shiny new mac...

I get no error message when executing mono WallParse.exe, instead the cpu goes up to 99% for the mono process. I thereafter thought that I could load the classes into my own c# application using reflection.

```
Assembly assemblytest  = Assembly.LoadFrom("WallParse.exe");
```

But this fails as well. The mono just pushes the cpu up to 99%. The .net application seems to be obfuscated... can this have something to do with it?